# Как очистить кэш файлов css и js на определенном сайте?

Tags: javascript, css, кэширование, браузер

У меня есть тестовый домен для проверки и демонстрации сайта заказчику. Раньше, для того, чтобы очистить старый кэш css и js файлов я пользовался сочетанием клавиш ctrl + f5, но по непонятным причинам эта функция перестала работать адекватно. Даже с открытой консолью отладки, во вкладке network, где стоит галочка с отключенным кэшом, все работает также криво или вообще не работает. Иногда просто сбрасывается все назад, бывает что css сбрасывается, а js не хочет иногда срабатывает. Знаю про способы записи файла вот так style.css?v=1.0.0, но для тестового сайта такой техникой нет желания пользоваться. Пробовал открывать консоль отладки, зажимать левой клавишей мыши на кнопке перезагрузки сайта и выбирать "Очистка кэша и жесткая перезагрузка" - никакого эффекта. Также очистка истории не помогает, хотя раньше все это работало, приходится заходить в другой браузер и уже там смотреть изменения, но заказчику такое не особо подходит. Как быть? Может кто сталкивался

Comment: Вы как-то генерируете HTML страницу, в которой подключается CSS и JS? Например при помощи PHP или Node?

Comment: Нет, если бы я генерировал это дело при помощи php или nodejs, то можно было придумать много решений данной проблемы. Я использую статические страницы, а в дальнейшем использую cms

Comment: Поэтому мне нужно показывать заказчику то, что правки внесены, но сбросить кэш css и js у меня перестало получаться

Comment: Можно динамически подключать файлы при помощи JS. Как показано здесь https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-js-css-files-to-reflect-latest-chan/ К имени файла добавляется timestamp и заказчик всегда видит самые свежие файлы.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо